# Reserve bandwidth for system (CentOs 7)

Tags: centos, bandwidth, bandwidth-control

There are CentOs 7 server used like video file server. Users download video files from there. Download speed are limited. But 1 time per day server becomes unreachable and unpingable, Only reboot helps. So, is there a way to reserve guaranteed bandwidth for system only?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the network bandwith is responsible for this. It is more probably that the system is working over capacity. Monitor the usage of your system, especially IO

Comment: Especially IO caused by memory exhaustion/heavy swapping due to some type of daily cron job.